# Using a Dutchman to completely fill a mortise lock hole

Tags: repair, doors, lock, mortise

I came across a [This Old House video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lMiTdVM7bik) that demonstrates how to fill a mortise lock with a Dutchman. The video patches one side of the door.

[image]

I want to patch both sides so I can drill it out and replace it with a modern door lever.

In the video, I believe they are repairing a previous patch so they can reinstall a mortise lock. Because I want to fill the cavity, should I simply cut each side deeper and at different sizes so the smaller insert uses the larger insert for glue backing?

[image]

What's the preferred method for completely filling the mortise with new wood?

Comment: A photo of your door will help. No need to put a Dutchman in on each side, just cut out a nice new hole with squared corners and fill with a patch of new wood. Create your patch piece  first and then use it to size    the hole in the door.

Comment: I have moved away from using "Dutchman" fill on door lock holes and now primarily use high-performance 2-part wood filler (very similar to auto-body filler). It sets fairly quickly, is strong, holds well, and it easy to plane, shape, and sand smooth. And can be drilled through nicely, even partially drilled for holes that span filler and wood.

Comment: I like your two sided Dutchman, especially the drawing! Based on the screen cap you shared, I'd put the bigger piece on the "up" side and glue it in place, then square out the bottom side and put the smaller piece in there. Sure, @JimmyFix-it's wood filler may be quicker, but there's a certain satisfaction to the craftsmanship of the Dutchman. Of course, if you're not interested in that aspect, go with the filler. Also, if you're going to stain & not paint, then your only option is wood.

Comment: just find a mortice lock that will work with your lever.